# Reusing the jQuery's getJSON more times in a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to read and parse JSON data using JavaScript. I can do this using jQuery, inside of an HTML page. For the **languages** JSON content

```
{ "json":
    { "languages" :
        [
            {"language":
                {
                    "text":"Deutsch",
                    "id":"ce4bb97b-8a8f-40c1-b4d7-34ebc8872ccd",
                    "code":"de"
                }
            },
            {"language":
                {
                    "text":"English",
                    "id":"1aaafaae-8dff-4055-9736-3970c9f6844b",
                    "code":"en"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I use this JavaScript to get the ID for the first language:

```
$.getJSON("languages.json", function(data, status) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    $("#languages").html(obj.json.languages[0].language.id);
}).done(function() {
    console.log("done success");
}).fail(function() {
    console.log("fail error");
}).always(function() {
    console.log("always complete");
});
```

But I would reuse this mechanism for more JSON contents, soomething like this:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var language_id = getLanguages()[0];
    });
})(jQuery);

function getLanguages() {
    var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(getJsonData("languages.json")));
    return obj.json.languages;
} 

function getJsonData(file) {
    return $.getJSON(file, function(data, status) {
        ...
    });
}
```

What is the best practice?

Comment: You can't return anything from an async function. `obj` in your example would be a reference to the `jqXHR` object returned from `$.getJSON()`, not the data received from the request. To fix this use callback or promises - see the duplicate for more information on working with this pattern

Comment: Well it is npt possible to return with an asynchronous call so not going to happen the way you tried

Comment: `var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(getJsonData("languages.json")));` will not work because your `getJsonData()` function returns a `Promise` object, not the actual data. The data is only accessible once the callback supplied to $.getJSON has been executed...this is because the request is asynchronous.

Comment: If you want to re-use the data outside the callback, then either a) in the callback, assign the result to a global variable (or at least a variable with high enough scope to be useful to you)...but that has its own downsides in terms of integrity of your code design, or b) you do what your getJsonData() is doing and return a `Promise`...then any code which actually needs the data can call the function, get the Promise, put its own "done" callback on the end of it, and then use the data once the callback has run. A Promise can have as many "done" callbacks attached as you wish.

Comment: The duplicate question now being shown above has a more comprehensive explanation in the answers, I suggest you study the examples.